# undefined is not a function 'navigation.navigate'

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am testing something in React-Native and I have an error with *React-Navigation* library that said: **TypeError:undefined is not a function(evaluating 'navigation.navigate')**.
Based to official documentation of react-navigation library I have done the code:

Navigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import MainScreen from './History';
import AirmineScreen from './AirmineApp';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    MainScreen: {screen:MainScreen},
    HistoryScreen: {screen: HistoryScreen}
});

const Navigation = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default Navigation;
```

Main.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
...
render(){
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
            navigation.navigate('HistoryScreen')}>
                <Text>history</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Comment: what is the **Main.js**'s class name? Is class name **MainScreen** right?

Comment: Your `navigation.js` imports `MainScreen` from `./History`. Perhaps that's the culprit?